# How to push up notifications from backend with flutter without firebase nor one signal?

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I have searched Google, YouTube and stack overflow for the answer but I haven't found any real solution.

I want to implement my own push notification solution on flutter, without firebase nor One signal. I do not want to depend on a third party service.

My Backend is on GoLang with graphql.
On the frontend, I am using a block pattern (flutter_bloc v6) and graphql_flutter v4.

I am using graphql subscriptions, so whenever the Backend emits a signal, the flutter app is able to receive it immediately.

I would like to be able to push up notifications to my users whenever the Backend sends some information, no matter if the app is on the foreground, background, closed or whatever. I do not want scheduled notifications either (aka flutter_local_notifications)

Comment: Checkout https://ravenapp.dev if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use a third service other than firebase/one signal?
Then you can try airship(https://docs.airship.com/reference/messages/message-types/push-notifications/)

But if you want to setup your own provider server, please check this page(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server), this is the start point, from where you can start your investigation and development.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to create your own backend system to send push notifications to the device. You have to develop Native Application for iOS and Android going beyond flutter. The local push notification could be used but you need to develop a custom notification receiver that will respond to the notification call back from the server in the background.